# NET CORE WEB - How do I check,if the database was updated correctly in the POST method?

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, http-post

*ASP NET CORE - WEB (using net core 3.0 and entity framework core)*
**In my method POST, I receive the elements from the View, then I want to save them into the Database. I do that, but how to check if something goes wrong ?**
POST METHOD:

```
public ViewResult EditBook(EditBookViewModels model)
    {
        //Get the book from the database
        BooksDisplayed book = _bookStore.GetSpecificBook(model.Id);
        //Check for the book
        if (book == null)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Book with the respective ID:{model.Id} cannot be found.";
            return View("NotFound");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            book.BooksInStore = model.BooksInStore;
            book.BookGenre = model.BookGenre;
            book.StockOfBooks = model.StockOfBooks;
            book.Price = model.Price;

            _bookStore.UpdateBook(book);
        }
        return View(model);
        //how to check if the object has been updated in the database ?
    }
```

Where I used before the built in classes UserManager and IdentityResult, it was ok, because in IdentityResult you have the property Succeeded, so than I could add the errors to the modelstate. It's clearly that somewhere in the code the IdentityResult is inherited. So I did check on microsoft page:
[CHECK POST METHOD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and they are using a try catch and DbUpdateConcurrencyException.
I should do the same ? Thank you.

Comment: You'll only get a concurrency exception if your database has a concurrency column, and you pass the previous value around in the view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use the Try-Catch statement to check whether there has an exception, if there is no exception, it means the update statements executed successfully.

But, the [DbUpdateConcurrencyException exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateconcurrencyexception?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) thrown by DbContext when it was expected that SaveChanges for an entity would result in a database update, but in fact no rows in the database were affected (concurrently updated). There might be have other exception which might cause the update to fail. SO, I suggest you could try to capture the [DbUpdateException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbupdateexception?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) or [Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception?view=netcore-3.1) exception. Code as below:

```
    try
    {
        _context.Update(movie);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex) 
    {
         //do something
    }
```

Or

```
    try
    {
        _context.Update(movie);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         //do something
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, than I will use a a try catch and a boolean property. Which, than gives me the possibility to return a View, which states that there is an issue. @zhi-lv-msft

Comment: My reputation doesn't let me :( @rychu151